# Django activate translations project wide instead of per view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-i18n, django-modeltranslation

I have a Django project where I activate the translations based on the `Accept-Language` header on each and every view as follows,

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate(request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'en'))
```

So if I have a ViewSet using Django Rest Framework, I had to do the above for each and every methods as following,

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        translation.activate(request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'en'))
        # ....
    
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        translation.activate(request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'en'))
        # ....
    
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        translation.activate(request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'en'))
        # ....
    
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        translation.activate(request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'en'))
        # ....
```

This is just for a viewset, I currently have 10+ viewsets and Translations are needed for every viewset. This make the process even harder to maintain and results in much code duplication. How can I clean up this code to something like activating translations project wide, any options available to do?

thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleanest approach will be writing a mixin for translations. Something along the lines:

```
class ActivateTranslationMixin:
    def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        init_request = super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        translation.activate(request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'en'))
        return init_request
```

Then you inherit this mixin in all the views you need

```
class MyViewSet(ActivateTranslationMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
```

Never tried this way before but it should work.